# Объединение двух Data Frames по нечетким признака

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть два Data Frame.
Код для получения `df_1`:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'title_1': [' Дросселирующее устройство', ' Дросселирующее устройство', ' Дросселирующее устройство',
                                 'Блок с диафрагмой', 'Клапан запорный', 'Клапан запорный', 'Клапан запорный'],
                    'code_1': ['20KBA31BP002', '20KBA32BP002', '20KBA33BP002', '20KBA50CF001',
                              '20KBA31AA102', '20KBA32AA102', '20KBA33AA102'], 
                    'type': ['_', '_', '_', '05 ОСТ24.125.20-89', 'А10821-0200-15-З', 'А10821-0200-15-З', 'А10821-0200-15-З'],
                    'weight': ['40,1', '40,1', '40,1', '0', '7,6', '7,6', '7,6']})
```

Вывод `df_1`:

```
    title_1                          code_1     type               weight
0   Дросселирующее устройство   20KBA31BP002    _                   40,1
1   Дросселирующее устройство   20KBA32BP002    _                   40,1
2   Дросселирующее устройство   20KBA33BP002    _                   40,1
3   Блок с диафрагмой           20KBA50CF001    05 ОСТ24.125.20-89  0
4   Клапан запорный             20KBA31AA102    А10821-0200-15-З    7,6
5   Клапан запорный             20KBA32AA102    А10821-0200-15-З    7,6
6   Клапан запорный             20KBA33AA102    А10821-0200-15-З    7,6
```

Код для получения `df_2`:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'title_2': ['20KBA31BP002, 20KBA32BP002, 20KBA33BP002    ДРОССЕЛЬНАЯ ШАЙБА  Ду 80   Нж,  масса  2,86 кг',
                                'БЛОК С ДИАФРАГМОЙ  Ду  65                  05 ОСТ 24.125.20-89, Нж, масса  11,8 кг',
                                'Запорная арматура дренажей и воздушников \
                                 КЛАПАН ЗАПОРНЫЙ РУЧНОЙ С ЗАМКОМ       А 10821-0200-15-3   ТУ 422-21-52/08   \
                                 Ду 15, Рр=20 МПа   МАССА 7,6 кг ПЕРЕСЧЕТ ПО ВЕСУ:  365*7,6/10=277 руб.    '],
                    'cost': ['28 111,00', '45 125.36', '458.32']})
```

Вывод `df_2`:

```
                     title_2                          cost
0   20KBA31BP002, 20KBA32BP002, 20KBA33BP002 ДР...  28 111,00
1   БЛОК С ДИАФРАГМОЙ Ду 65 05 ...                  45 125.36
2   Запорная арматура дренажей и воздушников ...    458.32
```

Путем анализа данных `df_1` (колонки "`title_1`", "`code_1`", "`type`"и "`weight`") и `df_2` (колонка "`title_2`"), надо произвести их сопоставление для достижения следующего результата:

```
                 title_1             code_1     type                weight  title_2                                           cost
0   Дросселирующее устройство   20KBA31BP002    _                    40,1   20KBA31BP002, 20KBA32BP002, 20KBA33BP002 ДР...  28 111,00
1   Дросселирующее устройство   20KBA32BP002    _                    40,1   20KBA31BP002, 20KBA32BP002, 20KBA33BP002 ДР...  28 111,00
2   Дросселирующее устройство   20KBA33BP002    _                    40,1   20KBA31BP002, 20KBA32BP002, 20KBA33BP002 ДР...  28 111,00
3   Блок с диафрагмой           20KBA50CF001    05 ОСТ24.125.20-89  0       БЛОК С ДИАФРАГМОЙ Ду 65 05 ...  45 125.36
4   Клапан запорный             20KBA31AA102    А10821-0200-15-З    7,6     Запорная арматура дренажей и воздушников ...    458.32
5   Клапан запорный             20KBA32AA102    А10821-0200-15-З    7,6     Запорная арматура дренажей и воздушников ...    458.32
6   Клапан запорный             20KBA33AA102    А10821-0200-15-З    7,6     Запорная арматура дренажей и воздушников ...    458.32
```

В виду большого разнообразия определяющих признаков, хотелось-бы иметь решение максимально гибкое, возможно, с использованием машинного обучения.
Использованные признаки для сопоставления в данном примере:

*Для записей 1 - 3:* по данным колонки "`code_1`" и наименованию.

*Для записи 4:* по данным колонки "`type`" (05 ОСТ24.125.20-89) и наименованию.

*Для записей 5-7:* по данным в колонках "`type`" (А10821-0200-15-З) и "`weight`" (7,6).

Есть еще дополнительная колонка с техническими признаками (`df_1`), которую можно использовать дополнительно...

Comment: Я думаю решение на Pandas будет слишком громоздким и черезчур медленным и, скорее всего, не очень гибким. Вам скорее подойдут движки полнотекстового поиска на подобие `Solr` или `Elasticsearch`

Comment: MaxUСпасибо!
А если посмотреть на эту задачу, как на задачу классификации...
По сути, записи df_1 - это классы, и к этим классам надо отнести записи df_2.
Набор для обучения модели организовать можно...

Comment: Можете попробовать, но мне кажется вам понадобится огромная заведомо размеченная обучающая выборка, чтобы точность предсказаний была нормальной. Судя по описанию в вопросе это скорее задача полнотекстового поиска...